# Which MVC flavor is more widely accepted?

Tags: model-view-controller

I notice 2 distinct "flavors" of MVC:

1) "Original" MVC where the Model talks directly to the View
2) "Apple Cocoa" MVC where the Controller uses the Mediator pattern and Model and View never communicate directly

From [link text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller):

> The goal of MVC is, by decoupling models and views, to reduce the complexity in architectural design and to increase flexibility and maintainability of code.

That makes great sense to me.  However with #1, as shown on wikipedia, you have a link between Model and View and therefore they seem quite coupled to me.  It seems like "original" MVC does not solve it's goal.

In contrast, #2 to me very clearly results in a generic View that only knows how to display and input data via UI, a Model that does not care at all about how it is represented, and a Controller that knows about both and becomes the only potentially un-reusable code.  It achieves the MVC goal.

This is good for me because I'm working in Cocoa which "Believes in" #2, and I'm working in plain C++ which I can make believe in anything.  But which of these MVC flavors will I find out in the wild more?  For instance, Ruby on Rails, Struts, PureMVC.. these "use MVC" but would I expect to see #1 or #2 there?

*EDIT:* Sounds like #2 is the more accepted one, so does *any* modern approach use #1, if so then what?

Comment: What is the example of Model #1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's more universally accepted, but most people see Rails as being pretty much the 'spec' for MVC, and in Rails the model and view never (almost never) talk directly. The controller does all the finding and sending of model data to the view.

Comment: MVC was created in SmallTalk in the 1970s. Rails was released in 2004. What gives you the impression that Rails is the authoritative source on MVC? (serious question, not being snide)

Comment: Hey @Jeff, I would not answer this question the same way today. This answer was based on my experience in web development at the time.

Comment: The answer boils down to 'rails does it this way' and doesn't help. I think the truth is closer to their being many flavors of MVC, none are universally excepted. MVC isn't a pattern but a higher level concept with many different concrete patterns depending on which framework you use. There is no way that the same MVC for the web can work for the desktop application, because for a start it needs to work around statelessness. Therefore the model and view cannot talk (rather than shouldn't talk). The textbox element rendered in Chrome cannot talk to the model on your server (putting ajax aside)

Answer (score 1):

In asp.net Mvc the #2 approach is taken: the controller reads and writes from/to the model, sends and receives data to/from the views. Views and models never talk directly.

Comment: Very true. But did they name it wrong instead of naming it as MVP? Because in MVP presenter is the one that comes in between view and model.